# PHP delimiters and WordPress (functions.php in specific)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, delimiter

I am modifying the functions.php file of a child theme in a wordpress installation.

At some point I want a function to produce html and then proceed as a normal function.

The "normal" way for me to code this would be like that:

```
<?php
/**
 * Child Theme
 * Author: Seb
**/

function html_output() {
 # some php code here
 ?> // closing php delimiter
 // some html code here
<?php } # opening php delimiter to close the function
# more php code here
```

However, when looking at code from other people online, the last two lines are like this:

```
<?php } ?> // opening php delimiter to close the function and then closing delimiter
<?php # random (?) extra php delimiter I don't get the meaning of
```

The editor (Coda and Sublime Text 2) doesn't complain about my code but it doesn't work. Can someone maybe explain to me why this has to be like that in order to function properly?

EDIT:

To make my question more clear, I don't understand how

`<?php }`

is different to

```
<?php } ?>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure about your question, but I got two thing in my mind

1. Coding Style for each developer differs ( while keeping the code
   healthy , and as per the standard being used on that specific
   framework)
2. it is a practice, I have often noted that you always have an `OPENED
   <?PHP` tag in code, the reason what I think I read somewhere was that ,
   it helps us avoid **HEADERS ALREADY SENT ON LINE.....** ERROR
3. Also, this opened `<?php` tags denoted that you have a php file and if
   you want to add any peice of code after this, you have to follow
   *PHP standards / rules* in mind

Okay

for php point of view

```
<?php } ?>
<?php
```

and

```
<?php }
```

both are okay, and they are as per php rules, but when it comes to WP, where, you get your final html rendered by including 3 or more than files, sometime, it becomes problematic....think the following situation

**header.php**

```
<?php }
```

and now, **contents.php**

```
<?php

//and some php code goes here
```

say, to load the page, both files are combined, so final output would be something like

```
 <?php }
<?php

    //and some php code goes here
```

just trying to explain you the situation with an example, not specific thoug...